# Cannot access fields of JSON objects in an array Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I am new to Javascript and React. I am trying to work with what is, to my understanding, a JSON object I am receiving from my database, and am storing in variable `UPCOMING`.

Here is the format of the JSON:

```
[
   {
      "start":"2022-03-30T04:00:00.000Z",
      "end":"2022-03-30T05:00:00.000Z",
      "role":"Cashier",
      "staffId":"staff_b520d594-068d-4b3e-a8d2-9f4d0e0fc2cc",
      "title":"Eudsokia Marisnette",
      "event_id":"schedule_16228a2b-eeb6-41cf-8f66-8d57cd1cb054"
   },
   {
      "start":"2022-03-25T04:00:00.000Z",
      "end":"2022-03-25T05:00:00.000Z",
      "role":"Cashier",
      "staffId":"staff_b520d594-068d-4b3e-a8d2-9f4d0e0fc2cc",
      "title":"Eudsokia Marisnette",
      "event_id":"schedule_40e06f22-7bd6-4f0b-80b4-4c59a35f0bc2"
   },
   {
      "start":"2022-03-29T04:00:00.000Z",
      "end":"2022-03-29T05:00:00.000Z",
      "role":"Cashier",
      "staffId":"staff_b520d594-068d-4b3e-a8d2-9f4d0e0fc2cc",
      "title":"Eudsokia Marisnette",
      "event_id":"schedule_46c87309-c706-41ba-ac0c-641ac987e592"
   },
   {
      "start":"2022-03-27T04:00:00.000Z",
      "end":"2022-03-27T05:00:00.000Z",
      "role":"Cashier",
      "staffId":"staff_b520d594-068d-4b3e-a8d2-9f4d0e0fc2cc",
      "title":"Eudsokia Marisnette",
      "event_id":"schedule_4ab4e333-76d5-4bb0-94d5-429352d6d518"
   },
   {
      "start":"2022-03-24T21:00:00.000Z",
      "end":"2022-03-24T22:00:00.000Z",
      "role":"Cashier",
      "staffId":"staff_b520d594-068d-4b3e-a8d2-9f4d0e0fc2cc",
      "title":"Eudsokia Marisnette",
      "event_id":"schedule_4b00d95c-931d-424b-a86e-7af43d3717a1"
   },
   {
      "start":"2022-03-28T04:00:00.000Z",
      "end":"2022-03-28T05:00:00.000Z",
      "role":"Cashier",
      "staffId":"staff_b520d594-068d-4b3e-a8d2-9f4d0e0fc2cc",
      "title":"Eudsokia Marisnette",
      "event_id":"schedule_78a6aa4b-688c-454c-8d2e-227d67ab521a"
   },
   {
      "start":"2022-03-26T04:00:00.000Z",
      "end":"2022-03-26T05:00:00.000Z",
      "role":"Cashier",
      "staffId":"staff_b520d594-068d-4b3e-a8d2-9f4d0e0fc2cc",
      "title":"Eudsokia Marisnette",
      "event_id":"schedule_f12cf70e-b96b-47ca-893d-384477c4d80b"
   }
]
```

When ever I do something like `<p>{JSON.stringify(UPCOMING)}</p>` or `<p>{JSON.stringify(UPCOMING[0])}</p>` it will render to the screen as expected. However if I try something like `<p>{JSON.stringify(UPCOMING[0].title)}</p>`, the entire screen in the browser goes white.

Additionally, I get the following error message in the console: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'title')`. If I am understanding the error correctly, it is essentially saying that the value is undefined, therefore it cannot show on screen?

How can I get the fields of the objects within this JSON without this white screen error occurring?

Comment: I think you don't need to "stringify" the array, simply use UPCOMING[x].title, where "x" is a position of the array

Comment: For instance, could use ` UPCOMING.forEach(e => { console.log(e) }) ` in the scripting section

Comment: yeah, you don't need to use stringify here, you can just use map function on your array, here's a demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kv2jhv

Comment: @Guille is correct. <p>{UPCOMING[0].title}</p> works in this case.

Comment: maybe it's better to iterate `UPCOMING` and for every value show the desired properties.

Comment: @Guille I tried that as well. It seems like any attempt to retrieve an element from a JSON object within the array is causing the same errors.